# Ways to pass $USER (or it's equivalent) to --chdir in Slurm

Tags: environment-variables, slurm, sbatch

### The Problem

I am attempting to create a script which automagically sets the directory in which to run an sbatch command with `--chdir` using a variable.  My goal is to create a single template file that is easy for less experienced users to run my code with.

### The Environment

In system I am running on, all users have a large file storage directory assigned to them which looks like `/path/$USER`.  The path is not the `$HOME` directory and is not stored as an environmental variable elsewhere.  All users are assigned a Slurm account where the Slurm username matches `$USER`.  This means that the Slurm-specific variable `%u` is the same as `$USER`.

### Minimal (non)-Working Example

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --partition=debug_5min
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=4000
#SBATCH --output=jobname_%J_stdout.txt
#SBATCH --error=jobname_%J_stderr.txt
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00
#SBATCH --job-name=user_pass
#SBATCH --chdir=/path/%u
#
################################################

touch testfile.txt
```

### Result of MnWE

The batch executes, and no files (testfile.txt, stdout, stderr) are generated on run completion.  If I do some digging on this test script, I am told that the run fails and that output was redirected to `/tmp/`.

### What works, but doesn't achieve the goal

Instead of executing `sbatch test.sh` directly, I can pass `--chdir` prior to the script, allowing me to use `$USER`.  The command looks like:

```
sbatch --chdir=/path/$USER test.sh
```

But this does not solve the original goal to make a script which does not require the end user to think too hard if they are scared of terminals.

### The Question - Restated

Is there a way to use variables in `--chdir` sbatch headers?

Why is `%u` not behaving like I would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to replace the `--chdir` parameter with a call to the `cd` command and give absolute paths for the `--output` and `--error` directives:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --partition=debug_5min
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=4000
#SBATCH --output=/path/%u/jobname_%J_stdout.txt
#SBATCH --error=/path/%u/jobname_%J_stderr.txt
#SBATCH --time=00:05:00
#SBATCH --job-name=user_pass
#
################################################
cd /path/$USER || exit -1 
touch testfile.txt
```

As for your restated questions, Bash will not expand variables in the `#SBATCH  ...` lines as those are seen as comments by the interpreter, and Slurm makes no effort to do that job.

And the `--chdir` parameter simply does not accept patterns (like `%u`); only simple strings.

Comment: Thanks for answering another Slurm directory question.  The ``--chdir`` not accepting patterns is really unfortunate.  Since other ``#SBATCH`` header options take variables, I wonder if this is a bug or intentional limitation of ``--chdir``.